# Project Migrated to Organization, but Not Showing Up in Organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I migrated an existing GCP Project to an Organization that I manage, and it shows up in my resources when I go to Manage Resources under IAM & Organizations. However, it doesn't show up in the Terminal when I use gcloud projects list --filter 'parent.id=XXXXX AND parent.type=organization'. Wondering if there's an additional setting that I'm missing.

The project appears in my Organization structure under Manage Resources but doesn't show up in the command line calling gcloud projects list --filter 'parent.id=XXXXX AND parent.type=organization'

The output from
`gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID`
is

```
createTime: '2018-11-02T15:05:33.142Z'
lifecycleState: ACTIVE
name: XXXX Project
parent:
  id: 'PARENT_ID'
  type: organization
projectId: PROJECT_ID
projectNumber: 'PROJECT_NUMBER'
```

The PARENT_ID is the correct Organization ID that I migrated the project into.

Comment: Edit your post and include the output from `gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID`. That command will tell you the parent id and type.

Comment: Could it be that the list is very long, perhaps use a | grep [project_ID]

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley - the post has been updated with the output.

Comment: Thanks @danyL - The list is actually quite short. So the pipe didn't give me anything new to work with.

Comment: Are you running the command on Windows, Linux or macOS? For Windows use double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm running it on Windows, but through the web CLI.